# Can't import another photos library into Photos

Tags: macos, photos

I'm trying to import another photo library (to merge it with my existing Photos library) using [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209528) .

However, I have fallen at the first hurdle: when I choose File... Import, I can't select the library file I want to import: it's greyed out.

[image]

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Apple's instructions require that the Library you're trying to import does _not_ have iCloud Photos enabled. Is iCloud Photos dis-enabled on every machine on which that Library exists?

Comment: so then I could open the library in photos, switch off iCloud photos, close the app, then retry?

Comment: Switch off iCloud Photos in all devices (Mac, iPhone, iPad) that contain the Libraries in question. Then restart the devices. Then try to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the reason I can't import any existing libraries was that I'm running Big Sur, not Monterey.

With apple's help, I managed to complete the merge as follows:

- open the other photo library
- set it as the system library
- enable iCloud

This only works because all the photos in my original library are being synced to iCloud.  And it is very slow.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it resolves your problem, it will avoid it being bumped by Community user as unanswered.